# DrRacket recursive function

Tags: recursion, racket

I'm new to the racket programming language so as a quick test, I typed this up on DrRacket:

```
>(define (test k)
 (when (not (= k 0))
  (begin
   k
    (test (- k 1)))))
>(test 5)
```

I expected an output of:
54321

but instead got nothing in return...

Tried an alternate approach:

```
>(define (test k)
  (when (not (= k 0))
   (begin
     (test (- k 1)) k)))
>(test 5)
```

but this only printed the number 5. I'm not sure what's going on. What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly *print* the value if you want it to be shown on the console, otherwise the line with the `k` is doing nothing - remember, Scheme is at its core a functional programming language, and a conditional returns the value of the *last* expression, all the others are just executed for the effect, but don't return a value.  A couple of tips:

```
(define (test k)
  (unless (zero? k)   ; use unless instead of when-not, zero? instead of (= x 0)
    (display k)       ; display prints in console
    (test (sub1 k)))) ; use sub1 instead of (- x 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried a different approach and that seemed to yield results:

```
> (define (prnt k) k)
> (define (test k)
 (when (not (= k 0))
  (begin
   (print k)
    (test (- k 1)))))
> (test 5)
```

This printed 54321 which is the behavior I expected. Not too sure why this works but previous attempts didn't but if anyone could shed light on the topic, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This works because you're using `(print k)` instead of just `k` in your original code. It's like saying `if(true) { x; return y; } else z;`, in this code, `y` is returned but `x` does absolutely nothing. `(if #t (begin x y) z)` works exactly the same way.